# how to animate "on page disappear" using css keyframe?

Tags: html, css

After discovering and using **keyframe**, I can add some animation on page loading. Like this http://jsbin.com/orusup/1/edit or like this on [graphicfusiondesign.com](http://graphicfusiondesign.com/blog/design/creating-fancy-css3-fade-in-animations-on-page-load/) ([demo](http://graphicfusiondesign.com/about-us/))

Now I want the inverse: add some animation on "page disappear". 
So when I click on any link, I got the same animation just before the next page/link loads.
I know it's easy in JavaScript but I want it in CSS only.

Comment: You can't have it in CSS only. JS i'm afraid.

Comment: Well may be ... But I had the same answer for the page load so...

Comment: "On page load" and "on page disappear" are too very different beasts.

Comment: Yeah you're right... But we never know.